# Predicting AWS RDS MySQL Instance Performance

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, aws, aws-aurora, amazon-rds-aurora

I have a small MySQL db running on `AWS RDS t2.small` instance.

So far, the CPU usage has been very predictable based on the traffic from my app.

**Example:**

```
1000 concurrent users = 15% CPU
2000 concurrent users = 30% CPU
3000 concurrent users = 45% CPU
4000 concurrent users = 60% CPU
```

My RDS is averaging just 15% with very predictable traffic spikes and I do have enough credits to cover the CPU spikes.

As my app is occasionally hitting 100% CPU, and since my "*Reserved*" instance will expire soon, I will have to soon decide on my next instance type.

As I'm not really able to benchmark the app/db and I will have to select another "*Reserved*" instance, considering all things being equal, the questions are:

Since the `t2.small` is only `1 vCPU | 2GB memory`, if I upgrade to `t3.medium` with `2 vCPU and 4GB of memory`, should I expect double capacity?

**T2.small vs T3.medium**

```
T2.small  | 1 vCPU | 2BG memory
T3.medium | 2 vCPU | 4GB memory
```

Should I expect the `t3.medium` will be running only at **30%** with **4000** concurrent users?

Considering my app usage is growing around 10% per month, should the `t3.medium` keep me running for another year?

I don't really have a budget for anything fancier, so unless the `AWS Aurora` would be a better option, I would like to stay with the T3 instance family.

Here is a CPU screenshot.

[image]

**SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%connect%'**

```
# Variable_name, Value
'Aborted_connects', '47'
'Connection_errors_accept', '0'
'Connection_errors_internal', '0'
'Connection_errors_max_connections', '0'
'Connection_errors_peer_address', '0'
'Connection_errors_select', '0'
'Connection_errors_tcpwrap', '0'
'Connections', '2986313'
'Max_used_connections', '113'
'Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost', '0'
'Ssl_client_connects', '0'
'Ssl_connect_renegotiates', '0'
'Ssl_finished_connects', '0'
'Threads_connected', '4'
```

Comment: AWS Aurora is much more LIMITED in tuning allowed in Parameter groups.  And innodb_io_capacity is limited to 200 and may not be modified for one of the 'limiting' Aurora factors.  RDS has much more flexibility for tuning higher volume.  Please post results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%connect%';

Comment: @WilsonHauck thanks for your feedback. As per your request, I have added the results for the: `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%connect%'`

Comment: t3.medium for 10% growth per MONTH might be reasonable for the next year.  Why do you expect 4000 concurrent users when at this point, after nearly 3 Million connections your max_used_connections was 113 (concurrent highest since instance start)?

Comment: @WilsonHauck sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear. These are not MySQL connections, but 4000 requests per minute through a load balancer. Pretty much, when I looked at the number of requests per minute, and compare them with my DB at the same time period, I can clearly see how is the traffic reflecting the CPU usage for my DB. So the question really was if having two CPUs and double memory will handle a double load. Is that the rule of thumb? Or is there some predicted performance loss when going from one to two CPUs and from two to four etc.

Comment: Context switching loss should be negligible at 4,000 requests per minute. 
 t3.medium should serve you well in AWS RDS. View my profile, Network profile for contact info.

Comment: When you need tuning assistance, please get in touch.

Comment: @WilsonHauck definitely will. I have already bookmarked your website after reading some of your other posts. BTW, while I have just recently upgraded this DB from magnetic storage to SSD, I think it may have reset the numbers, but regardless, it is my understanding that this t2.small instance has 140 connections limit anyway so I'm not sure if going from 113 to 140 would make much difference. the t3.medium has 312 connections limit. Can you perhaps comment on what will happen if you reach the connection limit?

Comment: Connection attempt will be denied if already at limit.  If your version supports it, Connection_errors_max_connections from SHOW GLOBAL STATUS count will be incremented by 1.   SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'connection_errors_max_connections'; may be used to monitor if your version supports the counter.

Comment: Do you have the slowlog turned on?  It may indicate some queries that can be sped up, thereby giving you an extra buffer before running out of horsepower.